# Scheduling: tasks on machines

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider a one-machine model where we want to minimize $\sum_{j=1} ^{n} T_j$, where $T_j $ is the tardiness of a job. We define $T_j = max(0, L_j)$, with $L_j = C_j - d_j$.

$C_j$ is the completion time and $d_j$ is the due date of job $j$, so $L_j$ is the lateness. Furthermore define $p_j$ as the processing time of job $j$ on the machine .

Show that if $p_i < p_j$ and $d_i < d_j$, then there exists a optimal schedule where job $i$ is scheduled before job $j$.

How we can do this? When does an optimal schedule exists and how can we obtain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prove by incremental construction.  Assume you have an optimal schedule where $p_i < p_j$ and $d_i < d_j$, but job $i$ is scheduled *after* job $j$.  Then show that if you switch job $i$ and job $j$, you obtain a schedule that is at least as good as the original schedule (with respect to the total tardiness).  Repeat until the job sequence satisfies the stated condition for all pairs of jobs.  (That if $p_i < p_j$ and $d_i < d_j$, then job $i$ is scheduled before job $j$.)

Specifically, show that if you switch the two jobs, then the new $C_i$ is before the old $C_j$ (by an amount equal to $p_j-p_i$), and every job between job $i$ and job $j$ is also advanced by that same amount; and the new $C_j$ is equal to the old $C_i$ (and all subsequent jobs also have their original completion time).  Therefore the total tardiness is at least as good as the original.